# Ajax call for Rest Webservice in Jquery not working in Browser but working in Eclipse ide Browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, eclipse, rest, jsp

The below code is a call for rest web service in JSP page. When I try loading the JSP in eclipse ide browser, it displays a success message whereas it displays the error block when I loaded in the Browser(tried ie,FF,chrome). Could not able to assess the main reason why the error function is getting executed on loading of JSP page in external browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"http://localhost:8797/WSDemo/book?firstname=srinivas",
        dataType:"xml",
        //url:"http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all",
        //dataType:"json",
        success:function(result){
            alert("This is success");
            alert(result);
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What the error is saying?

Comment: you will need a server to serve ajax requests and change the url to that server

Comment: I am running the same on another port of Apache tomcat server to run the below application.
`http://localhost:8797/WSDemo/book`
The main doubt is, why it is success in eclipse ide browser and error in external browsers.